# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). answer rendring only for 10 characters

Tags: python, json, api, flask, raiseerror

```
@app.route('/api/<string:isbn>', methods = ['GET'])
def isbn(isbn):
#import api from Goodreads (stats)

    book_data = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn=:isbn",{'isbn':isbn}).fetchone()
    title = book_data['title']
    author = book_data['author']
    year = book_data['year'] 


    res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "4RbGuzka0IUcJWWk1mivqg", "isbns":isbn }).json()

    reviews_count = float(res['books'][0]['reviews_count'])
    avg_score = float(res['books'][0]['average_rating'])
    dic = {"title": title, "author":author, "year": year,"isbn":isbn,"reviews_count":reviews_count,"avg_score":avg_score}
    print(dic)
    return jsonify(dic)
```

can somebody please tell me what is wrong with this code, when i am specifying 10 characters isbn number it is giving me the right api. when the isbn number i specify is less than 10 characters i am getting internal server error as:

```
 line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: There is no valid ISBN which is not exactly 10 or 13 characters long.

Comment: the isbn number are stored in my database. a few are the ones i mentioned below

Comment: Then you have invalid ISBN numbers in your database. Try doing lookups on other ISBN services for these numbers and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
isbn = '1590388127'
result = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json",
                   params={"key": "4RbGuzka0IUcJWWk1mivqg", "isbns": isbn})

if result.status_code == 200:
    res = result.json()
else:  # print reason
    print(result.text)
```

The upper version works. However with e.g. '756403146' you get the response "'No books match those ISBNs.'" (in result.text). Hence, the isbn is not in the database. If you try to .json() the result of those responses you get the error message you posted.

Comment: for the isbn numbers which exists are also giving the error but i want the api for them too. please can you give me the exact code to deal with it.  and also when i use if res.status_code != 404:
        raise Exception("ERROR: NOT FOUND.")    i am getting the error like  line 135, in isbn
    raise Exception("ERROR: NOT FOUND.")
Exception: ERROR: NOT FOUND.

Comment: 1590388127,1423160924,048641423X,5559609129 these are a few with which it works properly. while 756403146,307265781,20306652 these are few with which it doesn't work; but it should work. these are less than 10 characters with which its not responding..

Comment: that isbn number is pressent in the database. i checked.

Answer (score 0):

Googling on the ISBN numbers you could not get to work which were posted [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862654/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0-answer?noredirect=1#comment111165653_62862973) reveals that they seem to have incorrectly had their leading zero dropped. (Many ISBN codes look like numbers, but the last character is often an alphabetic symbol, so you should not be able to handle them as integer values.)

Try padding with leading zeros so the code is always exactly 10 or 13 characters long; any other length is not a valid ISBN.

Probably fix this in the actual database, or even better, in whichever source provided the information in your database; you don't want to have to grapple with corrupted data like this going forward.

Comment: Your question should properly contain all the information you have provided; comments can and often should be removed. Perhaps you still want to update your question to make it self-contained.

Comment: If your database schema requires the ISBN field to be an `int` you will likely have rejected a largish number of valid ISBN:s as key constraint violations. Maybe go back and fix that too if you can.

Comment: In database its character varying type. And these isbn number i got from goodread. I just imported them into my data base. By adding zeros infront of them won't be wrong